# Power set, Why is a right?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

Can someone tell me why the first choice is the correct answer?

Comment: As a quick check:  You did notice the right-hand sides of (i) and (iv) are $S$ and that the relation in (ii) is ${}\subseteq{}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) $\{b\} \in S$.  This is false the set $\{b\}$ is not a member of S.  The members of S are:$a$, $b$, and the set $\{a\}$

ii) $\{a\} \subset P(S)$. This is subtle but that is false.  $\{a\} \subset S$ so $\{a\} \in P(S)$.  But P(S) is the set of all subsets. The only elements it has will be sets.  Any subset of P(S) will be a set containing subsets.  {a} is not a set of sets.  It is simply a set with an element.

Perhaps it will help to list the elements of P(S).  P(S) = {$\emptyset$, {a}, {b}, {a}, {a,b}, {a,{a}}, {b,{a}}, {a,b,{a}}}.  As you can see $a \not \in P(S)$  so $\{a\} \not \subset P(S)$.

iii){a,b} $\in P(S)$.  True.  {a,b} $\subset S$ so $\{a,b\} \in P(S)$.

The entire trick of these is to understand the difference between being an *element* of a set and being *in* the set versus being a subset *of* a set, and being comfortable with the idea of a "set of sets" having sets as its elements.

iv) $\{a,b\}\in S$.  False.  Again {a,b} is not an element of S.

v){{a}} $\in P(s)$.  True.  {{a}} $\subset S$ so $\{\{a\}\} \in P(S)$.

vi){a.{a}} $\in P(S)$.  True $\{a,\{a\}\} \subset S$ so $\{a,\{a\}\} \in P(S)$.

Comment: This may sound basic. What is the difference in between a set {b} and b ?

Comment: b is an element.  {b} is a set that contains the element.  2 is the number two.  {2} is a set containing the number two.  You must get used to the idea that we will talk about sets in one sentence and elements in another and that sets can contain sets as elements.

Comment: I didn't understand the second point. Can you explain ?

Comment: what second point?  b is b.  {b} is a set that contains b. {{b}} is a set that contains the set {b}.  These are three different things.  Consider the numbers, 1 and 2.  1 and 2 are numbers S = {1,2} is a set that contains numbers.  $\emptyset$, {1}, {2}, and {1,2} are subsets of S.  *None* of them are numbers. all of them are sets of numbers.  P(S) = {$\emptyset$, {1},{2},{1,2}} is the set of all subset of S.  It contains sets.  Every element is a set.  *NO* element is a number.  It's elements are all sets of numbers, but none of it's elements are numbers.

Comment: I meant the second point of your answer about why {a} is not a subset of a power set of A. A subset can be a one element set too, right ?if {1,2,3} is a set of S, then {1} is a subset of S. Why isn't {a} a subset of P(A) ?

Comment: {1} $\subset A$.  {1} $\in P(A)$.  But {1} $\not \subset P(A)$.  a $\in S$.  {a} $\subset S$.  {a} $\in P(S)$ but {a} $\not \subset P(A)$.  P(A) is the set of subsets of A.  It's *elements* are subsets of A..  But the subsets of P(A) will *not* be subsets of A but subsets of P(A).  In other word *sets* of subsets..

Comment: Let B = {1,2}.  The elements of B are: 1, 2.  1 $\in B$, 2 $\in$ B.  1 $\not \subset B$. 2 $\not \subset B$ The subsets of B are: $\emptyset$, {1}, {2}, {1,2}.  $\emptyset \subset B$.  {1} $\subset B$. {2} $\subset B$. {1,2} $\subset B$.  {1,2} = B.  $\emptyset \not \in B$. {1} $\not \in B$ {2} $\not \in B$, {1,2} $\not \in B.$  P(B) is the set of subsets of B.  I've listed them. These are the *elements* of P(B):$\emptyset$, {1} {2},{1,2}. $\emptyset \in P(B)$. {1} $\in P(B)$. {2} $\in$ P(B). {1,2} $\in B$. These are *elements* of P(B).  They are subsets of B.  But they are NOT subsets of P(B)

Comment: P(B) = {$\emptyset$, {1}, {2}, {1,2}}.  THESE are the subsets of P(B), these are the elements of P(P(B)) $\emptyset$, {$\emptyset$}, {{1}}, {{2}}, {{1,2}}, {$\emptyset$, {1}}, {$\emptyset$, {2}},{$\emptyset$, {1,2}}{{1}{2}},{{1}{1,2}},{{2}{1,2}},{$\emptyset$,{1},{2}},{$\emptyset$,{1},{1,2}},{$\emptyset$,{2},{1,2}},{{1},{2},{1,2}},{$\emptyset$,{1},{2},{1,2}}

Comment: {a} can not be a subset of *any* power set because it is not a set of sets.  It is a set with an element that is not a set.  A powerset is a set of sets so its subsets will all be sets of set. {a} is not a set of sets.  It is as subset of *A*.  So it is an *element* of P(A).  But it is not a subset of P(A).  You *must* learn the difference between being an *element* of a set and being a *subset* of a set.

Answer (score 2):

Power set is the set containing all subsets of S.
{a,b} is a subset of S. So, it is an element of P.
{{a}} is also a subset of S. So, it is an element of P.
similarly, the rest follow.

Answer (score 1):

The power set of a set is the set of all the subsets of a set.

We have that

$$S = \{a, b, \{a\}\}$$

Therefore, the power set would be:

$$P(S) = \{\{\}, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{\{a\}\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, \{a\}\}, \{b, \{a\}\}, \{a, b, \{a\}\}\}$$

Therefore, looking at the answers, we can deduce that (a). is the answer.